# Where is it preferred to place the answer to duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

Using the following assumption:

*If two questions are both equal to the same question, then they are equal to each other. 
Therefore, the answer to one of them is also the answer to another.*

And the following question are considered duplicate:

- [What does the keyword "new" does to a struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207488/what-does-the-keyword-new-does-to-a-struct-in-c)
- [If a struct is a value type why can I new it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590150/if-a-struct-is-a-value-type-why-can-i-new-it)

However, I think that to answer two duplicate questions with duplicate answers would just be seen as spam, so I currently leave only one.

But I'm not sure for *Where it is preferred to place the answer to duplicate questions?*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a moot point, because once a question is closed as a duplicate you can no longer answer it.

Before it is closed as a duplicate, if you know it's a duplicate for sure, then you can just answer the canonical question.  If the votes to close as duplicate haven't come in yet, and you're not sure, then just answer it.

I don't think you would usually need to leave duplicate answers, once you've answered one, just let it rest.